# I can't import data from gtm's data layer into my own database

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, google-tag-manager

I created a data layer in GTM ( Google Tag Manager ) and wrote a script to import the information reflected in this part into my own data store but something seems wrong.

[image: any my datablock in gtm]

[image: The tags I used]

I have a trigger called addToCard, and with this event, my script fires as it pulls the data but my data block looks empty as seen in the image

[image]

Please help, I can explain more details you want. at least give me advice..

```
<script>

    var SvstData={};
    
    
    var a = window['dataLayer']
    var x =[]
    var b
    a.forEach(item=>{
        if(item.event=="addToCart"){
            b=item
        }
    })
    if(a){
        b.ecommerce.add.products.forEach((item) = function() {

            x.push({
                pId: item.id,
                pQty: item.quantity,
                pPrice: item.price,
                pName: item.name,
                url: '0',
                pimg: '0',
                image_url: '0',
                category_name: item.category,
                category_id: '0',
                brand: item.brand,
                brand_id: '0',
                product_code: '0',
                title: item.name,
                currency: '0',
                price_sell: item.price,
                price_order_general: item.price
            })
        })
        SvstData.product = x
        SvstData.count = x.length
        SvstData.email= a[2].userinfo.email;
        SvstData.oAmt= a[4].ecommerce.checkout.products[0].price;
        SvstData.oID= a[4].ecommerce.checkout.products[0].id;
    }
    
    SvstData.status= "cart";

</script>
```

I want to pass information from GTM data layer to my own data block

Comment: did you debug your code in the console? does it work there?

Comment: Definitely, I can say for now that I can also mirror the data to the console. I will add and update the image shortly. For now, my current problem is that the data in the console is not added to my own database, so I will open a current task for this.

Comment: You want to keep your question as minimal as possible. If you're not able to pass the data from the console, then by involving GTM in your question you're expanding it needlessly. Please shave off irrelevant details.